# iTextSharp PdfPCell.VerticalAlignment does Not work in text mode

Tags: itext

I am new to iTextSharp. In the below code setting VerticalAlignment for PdfPCell (I think in text mode) does Not do anything, text is still aligned to bottom of cell. 
According to multiple online examples, it should work, but does Not.  Setting HorizontalAlignment works.
Please help. Thank you

```
table = new PdfPTable(5);

Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
document.Open();

PdfPTable headerTable = new PdfPTable(3);
float[] headerWidths = { 2f, 5f, 2f };
headerTable.SetWidths(headerWidths);

myFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL);
PdfPCell myCell = setupHeaderCell("My Text", myFont);


// ADD headerTable to MainTable
// Creates a PdfPCell that accepts the headerTable as a parameter and then adds that cell to the main PdfPTable.
PdfPCell cellHeader = new PdfPCell(headerTable);
cellHeader.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;
// Sets the column span of the header cell to dataColumNb.
cellHeader.Colspan = 5;
// Adds the above header cell to the table.
table.AddCell(cellHeader);
................

}

private PdfPCell setupHeaderCell(string lineText, Font myFont)
{            
   var cl = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(lineText, myFont);
   cl.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;  // does Not change vertical alignment

   return cl;
}
```

Comment: What iText version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You've got nested tables so I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do. The `VerticalAlignment` is relative to the contents of the cell, not the cell itself, but I'm not sure if that's your problem. While troubleshooting this we need to simply things by removing the complexities and finding the least complex version that still produces the issue. I've tested the below code against iTextSharp 5.4.4 and it correctly vertically aligns the left-most column. Start with this, slowly add your logic and possible include some drawings and/or screenshots of what you expect and get.

```
var t2 = new PdfPTable(3);
float[] headerWidths = { 2f, 5f, 2f };
t2.SetWidths(headerWidths);

var cl = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Test"));
cl.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;

t2.AddCell(cl);

t2.AddCell("This\nIs\nMore\nText");
t2.AddCell("This\nIs\nMore\nText");
```

Comment: Just a heads up: the OP needs to give the iText version, there were some issues with nested tables recently.